# Cannot build a docker image with .Net 5 Preview 6

Tags: .net, docker, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I am having difficulties building a docker image on Visual Studio 16.7 preview 3/4 both professional and enterprise using the .Net 5 preview 6. I was able to build the same image with .Net 5 preview 4.

I have created several other applications on the platform and they all are coming back with the same error. A snippet of the verbose output form the docker restore call is not providing much help.

I have attached the docker restore below

```
1>                                     1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=Dependency
1>                                     VersionRange=5.0.0-preview.6.20312.4
1>                             d2fef628-4d77-4524-aba7-77abe1702bc7
1>                                     Id=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
1>                                     IncludeAssets=runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive
1>                                     MSBuildSourceProjectFile=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     MSBuildSourceTargetName=_IsProjectRestoreSupported
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     PrivateAssets=all
1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=Dependency
1>                                     VersionRange=5.0.0-preview.6.20312.4
1>                             adfcf5b5-8bf2-417c-81b9-6b5b8b4e50dd
1>                                     Id=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets
1>                                     MSBuildSourceProjectFile=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     MSBuildSourceTargetName=_IsProjectRestoreSupported
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=Dependency
1>                                     VersionRange=1.10.9
1>                             1f019172-3a10-49ee-840e-9ca0e75136f8
1>                                     Id=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
1>                                     MSBuildSourceProjectFile=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     MSBuildSourceTargetName=_IsProjectRestoreSupported
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=Dependency
1>                                     VersionRange=5.0.0-preview.6.20323.1
1>                             0adf02cb-ecc3-4546-97d5-f78dcb5d38a0
1>                                     Id=Microsoft.NETCore.App
1>                                     MSBuildSourceProjectFile=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     MSBuildSourceTargetName=_IsProjectRestoreSupported
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     PrivateAssets=All
1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=FrameworkReference
1>                             7714019b-17cc-4baf-872f-34c4f924ddf2
1>                                     Id=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
1>                                     MSBuildSourceProjectFile=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     MSBuildSourceTargetName=_IsProjectRestoreSupported
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     TargetFrameworks=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=FrameworkReference
1>                             02aaf514-cfb5-4a20-9c04-5537a3140ef5
1>                                     MSBuildSourceProjectFile=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     MSBuildSourceTargetName=_IsProjectRestoreSupported
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     RuntimeIdentifierGraphPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.6.20318.15\RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json
1>                                     TargetFramework=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=TargetFrameworkProperties
1>                             5f0f8101-d922-4bb4-b86d-fbf41f948a81
1>                                     AssetTargetFallback=;net461;net462;net47;net471;net472;net48
1>                                     MSBuildSourceProjectFile=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     MSBuildSourceTargetName=_IsProjectRestoreSupported
1>                                     OriginalItemSpec=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     PackageTargetFallback=
1>                                     ProjectUniqueName=C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj
1>                                     TargetFramework=netcoreapp5.0
1>                                     Type=TargetFrameworkInformation (TaskId:35)
1>                     Task Parameter:RestoreRecursive=True (TaskId:35)
1>                     Task Parameter:HideWarningsAndErrors=False (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestoreGraphItems Count '12' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestoreDisableParallel 'False' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestoreNoCache 'False' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestoreIgnoreFailedSources 'False' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestoreRecursive 'True' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestoreForce 'False' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) HideWarningsAndErrors 'False' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestoreForceEvaluate 'False' (TaskId:35)
1>                     (in) RestorePackagesConfig 'False' (TaskId:35)
1>                     Running restore with 2 concurrent jobs. (TaskId:35)
1>                     Reading project file C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj. (TaskId:35)
1>                     Restoring packages for C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj... (TaskId:35)
1>                     Restoring packages for .NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0... (TaskId:35)
1>10:28:17.605     1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.6.20318.15\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj]
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.6.20318.15\NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj]
1>                     NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
1>                      ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known.
1>                      ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): No such host is known.
1>                        at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs _)
1>                        at System.Net.Sockets.MultipleConnectAsync.AsyncFail(Exception e)
1>                        at System.Net.Sockets.MultipleConnectAsync.Fail(Boolean sync, Exception e)
1>                        at System.Net.Sockets.MultipleConnectAsync.DoDnsCallback(IAsyncResult result, Boolean sync)
1>                        at System.Net.Sockets.MultipleConnectAsync.DnsCallback(IAsyncResult result)
1>                        at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToApm.TaskAsyncResult.InvokeCallback()
1>                        at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<.cctor>b__17_0(Object state)
1>                        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
1>                        at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
1>                        at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.Run(Task task, Boolean canInlineContinuationTask)
1>                        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.RunContinuations(Object continuationObject)
1>                        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishSlow(Boolean userDelegateExecute)
1>                        at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.TrySetException(Object exceptionObject)
1>                        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception, Task`1& taskField)
1>                        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.SetException(Exception exception)
1>                        at System.Net.NameResolutionPal.GetAddrInfoExState.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
1>                        at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
1>                        at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
1>                     --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>                        at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>                        at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.ServerWarningLogHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceAuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationToken callerToken, Int64 timeoutTime)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>                     --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.TimeoutUtility.StartWithTimeout[T](Func`2 getTask, TimeSpan timeout, String timeoutMessage, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.SendAsync(HttpRetryHandlerRequest request, String source, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetThrottledResponse(Func`1 requestFactory, TimeSpan requestTimeout, TimeSpan downloadTimeout, Int32 maxTries, Boolean isRetry, Boolean isLastAttempt, Guid sessionId, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass14_0`1.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>                     --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>                        at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func`2 action, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T](HttpSourceCachedRequest request, Func`2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
1>                        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.TryCreate(SourceRepository source, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T]()
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.HttpFileSystemBasedFindPackageByIdResourceProvider.TryCreate(SourceRepository sourceRepository, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T]()
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.EnsureResource()
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryCoreAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<FindLibraryAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>                     --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.SourceRepositoryDependencyProvider.FindLibraryAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework targetFramework, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<<FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
1>                     --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryFromSourcesAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, IEnumerable`1 providers, Func`2 action)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryByVersionAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, IEnumerable`1 providers, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindPackageLibraryMatchAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, IEnumerable`1 remoteProviders, IEnumerable`1 localProviders, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryMatchAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, IEnumerable`1 remoteProviders, IEnumerable`1 localProviders, IEnumerable`1 projectProviders, IDictionary`2 lockFileLibraries, SourceCacheContext cacheContext, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.ResolverUtility.FindLibraryEntryAsync(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, RemoteWalkContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeName, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, Func`2 predicate, GraphEdge`1 outerEdge, TransitiveCentralPackageVersions transitiveCentralPackageVersions)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.CreateGraphNode(LibraryRange libraryRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeName, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, Func`2 predicate, GraphEdge`1 outerEdge, TransitiveCentralPackageVersions transitiveCentralPackageVersions)
1>                        at NuGet.DependencyResolver.RemoteDependencyWalker.WalkAsync(LibraryRange library, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, Boolean recursive)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.WalkDependenciesAsync(LibraryRange projectRange, NuGetFramework framework, String runtimeIdentifier, RuntimeGraph runtimeGraph, RemoteDependencyWalker walker, RemoteWalkContext context, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.ProjectRestoreCommand.TryRestoreAsync(LibraryRange projectRange, IEnumerable`1 frameworkRuntimePairs, NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, IReadOnlyList`1 fallbackPackageFolders, RemoteDependencyWalker remoteWalker, RemoteWalkContext context, Boolean forceRuntimeGraphCreation, CancellationToken token, TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteRestoreAsync(NuGetv3LocalRepository userPackageFolder, IReadOnlyList`1 fallbackPackageFolders, RemoteWalkContext context, CancellationToken token, TelemetryActivity telemetryActivity)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest summaryRequest, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAndCommitAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest summaryRequest, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.CompleteTaskAsync(List`1 restoreTasks)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunAsync(IEnumerable`1 restoreRequests, RestoreArgs restoreContext, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunAsync(RestoreArgs restoreContext, CancellationToken token)
1>                        at NuGet.Build.Tasks.BuildTasksUtility.RestoreAsync(DependencyGraphSpec dependencyGraphSpec, Boolean interactive, Boolean recursive, Boolean noCache, Boolean ignoreFailedSources, Boolean disableParallel, Boolean force, Boolean forceEvaluate, Boolean hideWarningsAndErrors, Boolean restorePC, Boolean cleanupAssetsForUnsupportedProjects, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
1>                        at NuGet.Build.Tasks.RestoreTask.ExecuteAsync(ILogger log) (TaskId:35)
1>                   Done executing task "RestoreTask" -- FAILED. (TaskId:35)
1>10:28:17.620     1>Done building target "Restore" in project "ESTemplateCompare.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:40)
1>10:28:17.621     1>Done Building Project "C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj" (Restore target(s)) -- FAILED.
1>Deferred Messages
1>10:28:17.622     0>
1>Detailed Build Summary
1>======================
1>     (TaskId:0)
1>
1>                     ============================== Build Hierarchy (IDs represent configurations) =====================================================
1>                     Id                  : Exclusive Time   Total Time   Path (Targets)
1>                     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (TaskId:0)
1>                     0                   : 48.514s           48.943s       C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj (Restore)  (TaskId:0)
1>                     | 1                 : 0.080s           0.080s       C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj (_IsProjectRestoreSupported)  (TaskId:0)
1>                     | 2                 : 0.008s           0.008s       C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj (_GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk)  (TaskId:0)
1>                     | 3                 : 0.321s           0.321s       C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj (_GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry)  (TaskId:0)
1>                     . 4                 : 0.019s           0.019s       C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj (_GenerateProjectRestoreGraph)  (TaskId:0)
1>
1>                     ============================== Node Utilization (IDs represent configurations) ====================================================
1>                     Timestamp:            1        Duration   Cumulative
1>                     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520486757108:   0        0.687s     0.687s ............. (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520493630106:   1        0.080s     0.768s . (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520494434294:   0        0.064s     0.832s . (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520495073101:   2        0.008s     0.840s  (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520495155880:   0        0.008s     0.848s  (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520495238347:   3        0.321s     1.169s ...... (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520498450550:   0        0.001s     1.171s  (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520498462291:   4        0.019s     1.190s  (TaskId:0)
1>                     637308520498653801:   0        47.757s     48.946s +++++++++ (scale 1:100) (TaskId:0)
1>                     -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1>                     Utilization:          100.0    Average Utilization: 100.0 (TaskId:0)
1>
1>Project Evaluation Performance Summary:
1>      621 ms  C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj   2 calls
1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
1>    48703 ms  C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj   6 calls
1>              48354 ms  Restore                                    1 calls
1>                  1 ms  _IsProjectRestoreSupported                 2 calls
1>                  8 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk            1 calls
1>                321 ms  _GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry          1 calls
1>                 19 ms  _GenerateProjectRestoreGraph               1 calls
1>
1>Target Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  _GetRestoreSettingsCurrentProject          1 calls
1>        0 ms  CollectCentralPackageVersions              1 calls
1>        0 ms  CollectFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  CollectPackageDownloads                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateRestoreDependencies               1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateProjectRestoreGraph               1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateRestoreGraphProjectEntry          1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateProjectRestoreGraphCurrentProject   1 calls
1>        0 ms  CollectPackageReferences                   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForObsoleteDotNetCliToolReferences   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetProjectJsonPath                        1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetRestoreSettingsPerFramework            1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedCppNETCoreVersion      2 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectPathItemsCurrentProject   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GetRestoreSettingsOverrides               1 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForUnsupportedNETCoreVersion         2 calls
1>        0 ms  _CheckForLanguageAndFeatureCombinationSupport   1 calls
1>        0 ms  _IsProjectRestoreSupported                 1 calls
1>        0 ms  _GenerateRestoreSpecs                      1 calls
1>        1 ms  _GenerateDotnetCliToolReferenceSpecs       1 calls
1>        1 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectPathWalk            1 calls
1>        2 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectPathItems           1 calls
1>        3 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectPathItemsPerFramework   1 calls
1>        4 ms  _GenerateProjectRestoreGraphPerFramework   1 calls
1>        4 ms  _GetRestoreTargetFrameworksOutput          1 calls
1>        5 ms  _GetRestoreProjectStyle                    1 calls
1>       11 ms  _GenerateRestoreProjectSpec                1 calls
1>       13 ms  _LoadRestoreGraphEntryPoints               1 calls
1>       16 ms  _GetAllRestoreProjectPathItems             1 calls
1>       16 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   1 calls
1>       20 ms  ApplyImplicitVersions                      1 calls
1>       43 ms  UpdateAspNetToFrameworkReference           1 calls
1>       65 ms  _GetRestoreSettings                        1 calls
1>      168 ms  ProcessFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
1>      218 ms  _FilterRestoreGraphProjectInputItems       1 calls
1>      346 ms  _GenerateRestoreGraph                      1 calls
1>    47754 ms  Restore                                    1 calls
1>
1>Task Performance Summary:
1>        0 ms  GetRestorePackageDownloadsTask             1 calls
1>        1 ms  GetRestoreFrameworkReferencesTask          1 calls
1>        1 ms  GetRestoreProjectReferencesTask            1 calls
1>        1 ms  GetRestoreDotnetCliToolsTask               1 calls
1>        1 ms  GetRestorePackageReferencesTask            1 calls
1>        2 ms  NuGetMessageTask                           1 calls
1>        2 ms  Message                                    3 calls
1>        2 ms  GetRestoreProjectStyleTask                 1 calls
1>        3 ms  GetProjectTargetFrameworksTask             1 calls
1>        3 ms  ConvertToAbsolutePath                      2 calls
1>        4 ms  CheckForDuplicateFrameworkReferences       1 calls
1>        4 ms  CheckIfPackageReferenceShouldBeFrameworkReference   2 calls
1>        7 ms  WarnForInvalidProjectsTask                 1 calls
1>       11 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           5 calls
1>       15 ms  CheckForImplicitPackageReferenceOverrides   1 calls
1>       19 ms  ApplyImplicitVersions                      1 calls
1>       65 ms  GetRestoreSettingsTask                     1 calls
1>       81 ms  ResolveAppHosts                            1 calls
1>       83 ms  ProcessFrameworkReferences                 1 calls
1>      481 ms  MsBuild                                    6 calls
1>    47753 ms  RestoreTask                                1 calls
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>                   "C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
1>                   (Restore target) ->
1>                     C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.6.20318.15\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. [C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj]
1>                   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100-preview.6.20318.15\NuGet.targets(128,5): error :   No such host is known. [C:\src\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare.csproj]
1>
1>    0 Warning(s)
1>    1 Error(s)
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:48.98
1>Removing intermediate container 25d77226c30c
1>The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore  -v diag "ESTemplateCompare/ESTemplateCompare.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
1>C:\Users\MArthur.PierreLouis\source\repos\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: Docker command failed with exit code 1.
1>C:\Users\MArthur.PierreLouis\source\repos\ESTemplateCompare\ESTemplateCompare\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: The command 'cmd /S /C dotnet restore  -v diag "ESTemplateCompare/ESTemplateCompare.csproj"' returned a non-zero code: 1
1>Done building project "ESTemplateCompare.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: New information. When I run *dotnet restore* on a copy on the project on the host, the restore is successful which seems to indicate that the base being used to create the image is insufficient somehow.

Comment: This looks to be just a DNS issue.  Have you tried adding a `RUN ping api.nuget.org` command to your Dockerfile to see if that even works?

Comment: Thanks. I will try that an report back

Comment: Indeed the host cannot be found. Ping works perfectly fine on the host. Great piece of info thank @MattThalman . If you know how I would fix that I would appreciate it but I have a great lead with your input.